# Visual c++ to turbo c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, turbo-c++

Hi I have written a program in visual c++ and for whatever reason now i need to run/compile this same program in turbo c++ 3.0.

I have managed to get the compiler from some source but I get a lot of errors when i try to compile my code. I have commented out "#include stdafx.h" set the appropriate paths for the directories and libraries in the ide. these are the lines that give me errors

```
#include <list> //Error unable to open include file list

using namespace std; //Declaration syntax error

typedef list<int> itemist; // , expected

bool setPlayerChar(char key); // Type name expected // Declaration missing ;

void generateItemList(piece market[9], itemlist &ilist) // ) expected

bool exit = false; // Undefined symbol 'bool' // statement missing ;
```

Comment: "Turbo C++ 3.0" as in "the 20 year old C++ compiler"?!

Comment: C++ wasn't standardized until seven years after this compiler was released. You might be looking at some refactoring if the compiler is choking on standard C++.

Comment: If I would really, **really** need this, I'd call Comeau and inquire about a custom cross-compiler.

Answer (score 5):

When Turbo C++ 3.0 was state-of-the-art several years ago, a lot of C++ things of today did not exist. No STL, no `<list>`, no namespaces, not even the type `bool` (was typically emulated by a macro 'BOOL'). When I remember correctly, it was just a 16 bit compiler, what gives you additional "fun" with `int` and pointer arithmetik.

Happy porting ;-)

Comment: Agreed. You're not going to be able to get this to "just work." Everything that has come into c++ since Turbo you're just going to have to write yourself.

Comment: In the age of C++11, turbo C++ does not deserve to be called "a C++ compiler"

Comment: It might have `list.h` though, not that it will help much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try these ugly hacks:

```
/* Check if the compiler is Borland Turbo C++ 3.0 or earlier */
#ifdef __BORLANDC__
#if (__BORLANDC__ <= 0x400)

#include <list.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true  (1)
#define false (0)

#else

#include <list>

#endif
```

and so on, but instead, consider using a more recent compiler, such as GCC or MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to run your application in DOS and the machine is at least 80386, I would suggest using [DJGPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djgpp). It provides recent GCC. Your application will then run in x86 protected mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build your program for DOS, you may try Borland C++ 5.02.
It is the last Borland's compiler that supported DOS, and included some pre-standard STL.

Code like this:

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

typedef list<int> itemist;
```

should be compilable with it.