# Code compilation fails on Turbo C++

Tags: c++

my code runs fine with VS Studio 2010 b, but as part of demo in college I have to present it on Turbo C++. Same code gives compilation erros like declaration syntax , type qualifier must be struct or class. I know Turbo C++ is kind of outdated now but somehow I will have to go with it. So I request all experts here to please provide me suggestion on things I should follow to make it work

```
#include <iostream.h>

//using namespace std;

class cSample
{
private:
    static const char *list1[];
    static const char *list2[];

public:
    cSample();
    const char **GetList(int);
    bool IsSampleWorking();
};

bool cSample::IsSampleWorking()
{
    return true;
}

cSample::cSample()
{
}

const char *cSample::list1[] = {"Item1" , "Item2" , "Item3" , NULL};
const char *cSample::list2[] = {"Item4" ,"Item5" ,"Item6" , NULL};

const char **cSample::GetList(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
    case 1:
        return cSample::list1;
        break;
    case 2:
        return cSample::list2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc , const char *argv[])
{
    cSample *oSample = new cSample();

    const char**list1Item = oSample->GetList(1);
    cout << "Items from List1 " << endl; 
    while(*list1Item != NULL)
    {
        cout << *list1Item << endl;
        list1Item++;
    }

    const char **list2Item = oSample->GetList(2);
    cout << "Items from list2" << endl;
    while(*list2Item != NULL)
    {
        cout << *list2Item << endl;
        list2Item++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Line 14 - Declaration missing and Type name expected
Line 17 - Declaration syntax error

Comment: give the exact error messages with line numbers

Comment: I have edited question description to provide information for errors I receive on Turbo C++

Comment: `Turbo C / C++ ver 3.0 for DOS does not offer bool primitive data type.` http://www.softwareandfinance.com/forums/index.php?topic=54.0

Comment: Turbo C++ is ancient — very ancient; it is pre-standard, pre-98.  That's why you have to use the archaic and very obsolete `<iostream.h>` header instead of the more modern and standard `<iostream>` header.  It is scary that you're expected to use technology that should not be allowed out of its grave!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339311/visual-c-to-turbo-c

Answer (score 4):

Your compiler is not considering bool as a type.

Option 1

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

Option 2

```
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
```